# ScalaCheck - Ordered array generator

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I am trying out ScalaCheck for the first time and I want to generate an ordered array of Ints.

I read the documentation and did some search but I didn't find a way to do it.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want an arbitrary array of integers that's been sorted, right? If that's the case, you can use either of the following approaches to get a `Gen[Array[Int]]`:

```
val genIntArray = Gen.containerOf[Array, Int](
  Gen.chooseNum(Int.MinValue, Int.MaxValue)
)
```

Or:

```
val genIntArray = implicitly[Arbitrary[Array[Int]]].arbitrary
```

You can then use `map` to modify the generator to sort its results:

```
 val genSortedIntArray = genIntArray.map(_.sorted)
```

Now you can run `genSortedIntArray.sample.get` a few times to convince yourself that the result is a sorted array of random integers.

If you want an `Arbitrary` for sorted arrays of integers, it's best to define a wrapper instead of hiding the default `Arbitrary[Array[Int]]`. For example, you could write the following:

```
case class SortedIntArray(value: Array[Int]) extends AnyVal

object SortedIntArray {
  implicit val arb: Arbitrary[SortedIntArray] = Arbitrary(
    genSortedIntArray.map(SortedIntArray(_))
  )
}
```

And then:

```
forAll { (a: SortedIntArray) =>
  confirmThatMyFunctionOnSortedIntArraysWorks(a.value)
}
```

Comment: When using specialized generators like this, I think it is better to avoid Arbitrary all together. You can just use your generator directly: forAll(genSortedIntArray) { a => ... }. It might be a matter of taste, however.